# How can I correct an error in C to autoit translation?

Tags: c, translation, autoit

C code:

```
u= (c1 & 0xff) * (c2 & 0xff) * (c3 & 0xff) * (c4 & 0xff) * (c5 & 0xff)
unsigned a, b, r;
u += 0xe91aaa35;
u ^= u >> 16;
u += u << 8;
u ^= u >> 4;
b  = (u >> 8) & 0x1ff;
a  = (u + (u << 2)) >> 19;
r  = a ^ table[b];
```

autoit code:

```
$u=(BitAND($c1, 0xFF)) * (BitAND($c2, 0xFF)) * (BitAND($c3, 0xFF)) * (BitAND($c4, 0xFF)) * (BitAND($c5, 0xFF))
dim $a,$b,$r
$u=$u+0xe91aaa35
$u=BitXOR($u, BitShift($u, 16))
$u=$u+(BitShift($u,-8))
$u=BitXOR($u, BitShift($u, 4))
$b = (BitShift($u, 8)) & 0x1FF
$a = BitShift(($u + (BitShift($u, -2)), 19) #I get this "ERROR: unbalanced parenthesis expression" here)
$r = BitXOR($a, $table[$b])
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's wrong and where. What's the problem?

Comment: Dim is not advised in this case, it has a very specific purpose and that's not it. Use Local instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the target language at all, but you are opening 4 `(` and closing just 3.